# Possible duplicate enumeration of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

I have wrote the following code:

```
IEnumerable<string> blackListCountriesCodes = 
pair.Criterion.CountriesExceptions.Select(countryItem => countryItem.CountryCode);

IEnumerable<string> whiteListCountriesCodes = 
pair.Criterion.Countries.Select(countryItem => countryItem.CountryCode);

return (!blackListCountriesCodes.Contains(Consts.ALL.ToString()) &&
        !blackListCountriesCodes.Contains(country) &&
        (whiteListCountriesCodes.Contains(Consts.ALL.ToString()) ||
        whiteListCountriesCodes.Contains(country)));
```

resharper shows me a warning:
`Possible duplicate enumeration of IEnumerable`

What does this mean? Why is this a warning?

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable (which is where you will go if you choose "Why is ReSharper suggesting this?" from the ReSharper inspection menu)

Comment: Also this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240844/handling-warning-for-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable

Comment: Here you have a trade off - unless the amount of data is huge (which I doubt - AFAIK countries in world < 1000) you can materialize `blackListCountriesCodes` and `whiteListCountriesCodes` before checking the predicates

Comment: @AakashM I want to get it clear: The code "remembers" it did this query already and will not re-do it? doesn't this cause not up-to-date data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LINQ Queries defer their execution until you do something with the results. In this case, calling `Contains()` twice on the same collection could cause the results to be enumerated twice which, depending on the query, could cause performance issues.

You can solve this by simply tacking a `ToList()` call on the end of your query which will force execution of the query and store the results a single time.

Comment: I still don't get it. i thought I should prefer lazy execution, no? If I apply `ToList()` and execute the first query, I lose the benefits of lazy execution. How can eager eaxecution solve performance issue? It sounds to be the other way arround. no?

Comment: @EladBenda - If you wait for lazy execution, and you're querying a database, the query will be executed needlessly at the database twice. If you call ToList, the query may be executed immediately, but the results will be stored and the query executed only once.

Comment: The code "remembers" it did this query already and will not re-do it? doesn't this cause not up-to-date data?

Answer (score 1):

This means that your code may enumerate the `blackListCountriesCodes` and `whiteListCountriesCodes` several times. Since LINQ uses deferred evaluation, this may cause slowness, especially when the `pair` has lots of data, and `Where` clauses are complex (it does not look like any of that applies in your situation, though).

You can eliminate the warning (and the alleged slowness) by "materializing" the enumerations into lists, like this:

```
var blackListCountriesCodes = 
    pair.Criterion.CountriesExceptions.Select(countryItem => countryItem.CountryCode).ToList();

var whiteListCountriesCodes = 
    pair.Criterion.Countries.Select(countryItem => countryItem.CountryCode).ToList();
```

Comment: how come defer execution is slower? It sounds to be the other way arround. no?
If I force execution- the code "remembers" it did this query already and will not re-do it? doesn't this cause not up-to-date data?

Comment: @EladBenda That depends a lot on where the data for the deferred execution comes from: if it comes from a list of 1000000 items of which 999900 are filtered out, then eagerly selecting 100 items into a separate list would be a significant performance improvement. Same goes for deferred read from RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you might calculate the content of the `IEnumerable` twice (or more). If this is expensive, like calling a database this is bad for performance. If the underlying source is a `List<T>` and there is a simple projection or something else non-expensive this is not a problem.

You could of course rewrite the expression to use the enumerables only once.

```
!blackListCountriesCodes.Contains(Consts.ALL.ToString())
    && !blackListCountriesCodes.Contains(country)
```

could be rewritten as

```
!blackListCountriesCodes
    .Where(blcc => blcc == Consts.ALL.ToString() || blcc == country).Any()
```

Comment: I still don't get it. i thought I should prefer lazy execution, no? If I apply `ToList()` and execute the first query, I lose the benefits of lazy execution. How can eager eaxecution solve performance issue? It sounds to be the other way arround. no?

Comment: If you only want to use the result 0-1 times and maybe only use parts of the result you should use Lazy evaluation, but if want to use the result many times you should not use lazy, at least not lazy where you recalculate the content. You could still use `Lazy<T>` to instantiate on first use.

Comment: you mean the The code "remembers" it did this query already and will not re-do it? doesn't this cause not up-to-date data?