# Resharper's example code for explaining "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable"

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-7.1

Sometimes Resharper warns about:

> Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable

There's [an SO question on how to handle this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8240844/419956), and the ReSharper site also explains things [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable). It has some sample code that tells you to do this instead:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = GetNames().ToList();
```

My question is about this specific suggestion: won't this still result in enumerating through the collection twice in the 2 for-each loops?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling warning for possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240844/handling-warning-for-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable)

Answer (score 196, accepted):

`GetNames()` returns an `IEnumerable`. So if you store that result:

```
IEnumerable foo = GetNames();
```

Then every time you enumerate `foo`, the `GetNames()` method is called again (not literally, I can't find a link that properly explains the details, but see [`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Resharper sees this, and suggests you to store the *result* of enumerating `GetNames()` in a local variable, for example by materializing it in a list:

```
IEnumerable fooEnumerated = GetNames().ToList();
```

This will make sure that the `GetNames()` result is only enumerated once, as long as you refer to `fooEnumerated`.

This does matter because you usually want to enumerate only once, for example when `GetNames()` performs a (slow) database call.

Because you *materialized* the results in a list, it doesn't matter anymore that you enumerate `fooEnumerated` twice; you'll be iterating over an in-memory list twice.

Comment: No. The GetEnumerator() method will only be invoked once in the foreach loop. The real reason is for the risk of dirty data. For example, in GetNames(), there is a SQL query, but only query which returns IEnurable. When you invoke .ToList(), you store all the data in memory, there is little risk of dirty data. But if there is much time between 2 loop oprations, if you excute SQL to database every time, then there is a big risk of dirty data.

Comment: @SunRobin this is an answer that presents the truth in simplified form, as is also mentioned in it. I haven't gotten around yet to improve it. Your use of "dirty data" may require some further explanation.

Comment: This is the url from Microsoft to tell us the inside implementation of foreach loop. You can see that the GetEnumerator() is only invoked once. And another thing we need to know is that IEnumerable is lazy loading when it is working with some ORM. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx If you just get the handler of Enumerator and not load all the data into memory, you may have some conflicts between the 2 operations with the same enumerator, someone has modified the database. To avoid this, Resharper suggest you to load the data into  Merroy through .ToList() method.

Comment: This answer is somewhat imprecise. Not every `IEnumerable` are evaluated for each enumeration, only those who are implemented with ['deferred execution'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) (That is is the link which you were lacking, @CodeCaster). The R# warning can be safely ignored when the underlying implementation is not deferred executed, as with this question example which calls `ToList()` to store it in another `IEnumerable` variable.

Comment: @Frédéric I know, and I've excused myself before. It's on my TODO-list to  improve this post. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster, no problem, I was coming from a recent answer linking there, and I added in it a brief [explanation](/questions/35635954/counting-non-faulted-tasks-causes-re-execution-of-each-task#comment58955158_35636420) of what was lacking imo. Feel free to reuse it if you like. Then I will probably delete my comments here once their wile be no more relevant.

Answer (score 11):

I found this to have the best and easiest way to understand multiple enumerations.

C# LINQ: Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable

https://helloacm.com/c-linq-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable-resharper/

Comment: You could point out special points of your link here.. but the link is nice --> +1

Answer (score 10):

`GetNames()` is not called twice. The implementation of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is called each time you want to enumerate the collection with `foreach`. If within the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` some expensive calculation is made this might be a reason to consider.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'll be enumerating it twice with no doubt. but the point is if `GetNames()` returns a lazy linq query which is very expensive to compute then it will compute **twice** without a call to `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a method returns IEnumerable doesn't mean there will be deferred execution.

E.g.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yolo");
    return new string[] { "Fred", "Wilma", "Betty", "Barney" };
}

var names = GetNames(); // Yolo prints out here! and only here!

foreach(name in names)
{
    // Some code...
}

foreach(name in names)
{
    // Some code...
}
```

Back to the question, if:

a. There is deferred execution (e.g. LINQ - .Where(), .Select(), etc.): then the method returns a "promise" that knows how to iterate over the collection. So when calling .ToList() this iteration happens and we store the list in memory.

b. There is no deferred execution (e.g. method returns a List): then assuming GetNames returns a list, it's basically like doing a .ToList() on that list

```
var names = GetNames().ToList(); 
//          1        2 3
```

1. Yolo Prints out
2. List is returned
3. ReturnedList.ToList() is called

PS, I left the following comment on [Resharper's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2020.3/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html#false-positives)

Hi,

> Can you please make it clear in the documentation that this'd only be
> an issue if GetNames() implements deferred execution?
>
> For example, if GetNames() uses yield under the hood or implements a
> deferred execution approach like most LINQ statements for example
> (.Select(), .Where(), etc.)
>
> Otherwise, if under the hood GetNames() is not returning an
> IEnumerable that implements defered execution, then there is no
> performance or data integrity issues here. E.g. if GetNames returns
> List