# can I get the latest file without calculating LastOrDefault

Tags: c#

Can I get the latest file within `foreach` loop without calculating `last` variable using `LastOrDefault` ?

**I don't want to repeat `archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime)` 2 times**

```
var last = archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime).LastOrDefault();

        foreach (var entry in archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Equals(last) ? $"latest file: {entry.Name}" : entry.Name);
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't want to repeat `archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime)` 2 times

Comment: Possibly that you can store the `IQueryable`/ `IOrderQueryable` into a variable. `var orderQuery = archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime);` Then you can use the variable to avoid duplication. `var last = orderQuery.Last();`

Comment: Note that it is deferred execution when declare into the variable (`IQueryable`). It won't materialize until call methods such: as `ToList()`, `Last()`, `First()`...

Comment: @YongShun. thanks, but I am getting warning `possible multiple enumeration` for variable `orderQuery`, how to avoid it?

Comment: Perhaps use `.ToList()` in `foreach (var entry in orderQuery.ToList())`. Maybe you can have a read on this question: [Resharper's example code for explaining "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129079/resharpers-example-code-for-explaining-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the chain of LINQ queries at any point and resume in another context.

```
// Note: ToArray() is necessary to prevent double-enumeration in the case of a Queryable set. 
// It's not necessary for constructs which are already enumerated
var ordered = archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime).ToArray(); 
var last = ordered.LastOrDefault();

foreach (var entry in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Equals(last) ? $"latest file: {entry.Name}" : entry.Name);
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't really help. It makes the code a bit more succinct but the LINQ query is still executed twice.

Comment: thanks. I am getting `possible multiple enumeration` for variable `ordered`, how to avoid it?

Comment: I updated the answer. I assumed Entries wasn't an Queryable. ToArray/ToList/toCollection() will enumerate the full set once. The answer technically "avoids duplicating the code" which the question called for. Duplication of the enumeration wasn't mentioned at the time.