# Class reference vs Interface reference

Tags: c#, interface, reference

I know it is very general question but I think it would be very beneficial for less experienced programmers to get clear answer.

Scenario:

Let say I have `MyClass` which is implementing interfaces `IMembers1`, `IMembers2`, `IMembers3`. `MyClass` also contains members which are not defined in any of those interfaces.

Question:

Is there any benefit in using f.e. `IMembers2` reference to access `IMembers2` members in `MyClass` instance instead accessing them by simply using `MyClass` reference.

If I have instance of type which is unknown at compile time but I'm sure it will implement `IMembers2` interface I would of course use `IMembers2` reference to access its members. Lots of code examples and tutorials are teaching to use f.e. `IEnumerable<T>` reference to access list collection in heap instead of using `List<T>` reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Comment: It depends. Will all classes always implement IMembers1, IMembers2, and IMembers3? If not, then it would be more flexible for methods to accept the interface they need as an argument.

Comment: Quote: "Lots of code examples and tutorials are teaching to use f.e. IEnumerable<T> reference to access list collection in heap instead of using List<T> reference." You should downgrade your opinion of things which teach that for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240935/5198140).